# How to send user to another page after login (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that checks to see if a user exists in a database...

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.log_username,
        password: req.body.log_password
    }, function (err, docs) {
        if (docs.length !== 0) {
            console.log("user exists");

        }
        else {
            console.log("no exist");
        }
    });

});
```

I have a home page that I want to send the user to if the login was a success. What should I put in the `if` statement to send the use to another page, in this case, `home.js`. `home.js` has the following code in it...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If it worked , mark it resolve

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz patience my friend, I always do

Comment: hahahaha.... wait is too bad thing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redirect the user to main page. **`res.redirect('path')`**

Reference : http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.log_username,
        password: req.body.log_password
    }, function (err, docs) {
        if (docs.length !== 0) {
            console.log("user exists");
            res.redirect('/'); // main page url
        }
        else {
            console.log("no exist");
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: i tried your answer but i have some issue, my server is on :1001 and the client on 3000 so when i do `res.redirect("/")` it's send to :1001/ and there is nothing so how can i `res.redirect("/")` to :3000 from server ?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose findOne will return 1 object as `result` else `null`. 
No need to check for `docs.length > 0` 
manual: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne)

Also added `req.session.user = result` maybe You'll need it to check if user authenticated (inside middleware function to prevent direct access to internal routes.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    User
      .findOne({
        username: req.body.log_username,
        password: req.body.log_password
      })
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if(result) { // auth was successful
          req.session.user = result; // so writing user document to session
          return res.redirect('/'); // redirecting user to interface
        }

        // auth not successful, because result is null
        res.redirect('/login'); // redirect to login page
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in middleware store originalUrl to session:

`req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;`

And change `successRedirect` to `successReturnToOrRedirect` param:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
     successReturnToOrRedirect: '/dashboard', // redirect to the secure profile section
     failureRedirect: '/login?Failed', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
     failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like

`res.redirect('/');`

in your POST to "/".

Example:

```
    if (docs.length !== 0) {
        console.log("user exists");
        res.redirect('/');
    }
```